# Export multiple queries from access into excel with different sheets

Tags: excel, export

Please kindly let me know how to export multiple queries from Access into one excel workbook with different worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

if you know java you can retreive data with jakcess or ucanaccess and then create the excel with apache poi project. I Aldo know that a software can do it easely, its name si qlikview.